# why is my palindrome program code RTE in online judge?

Tags: c++, c++17

so I have to code for palindrome numbers using recursive. if the number is a palindrome, then print "YA". if the number is not a palindrome, then print "BUKAN". Thanks before, and sorry for my bad english

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string pal(string s){
    if(s[0] != s[s.length()-1]){
        return "BUKAN";
    }else if(s.length() == 1){
        return "YA";
    }else{
        s = s.substr(1, s.length()-2);
        return pal(s);
    }
}

int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << pal(a);
}
```

Comment: If the string is long, all that string copying is going to take too much time.

Comment: Just replace `std::string` with `std::string_view`.

Comment: in what line? @Quimby

Comment: `string s` -> `string_view s`, although you'll need to `#include <string_view>`

Comment: The shown code will fail miserably for palindromes with an even number of letters. Furthermore, no recursion is required, and it only slows things down even more.

Comment: RTE: Return To England? Ready To Explode? Reasonable Time Estimate? Steven Segal's next movie?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose by RTE, you are trying to say Run Time Error. This is because of strings of even length. Let's say you input the string `a = "kk"`. When you reach the line,

```
s = s.substr(1, s.length()-2);
```

`s.length() = 2`, so you will be running

```
s = s.substr(1, 0);
```

which will result in

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)
```

or RTE (Run Time Error) on any Online Judge.

But even if you correct this mistake, you will face TLE(Time Limit Exceeded) and the detailed reason along with solution is given below.

---

In your recursive solution, you are using the `substr()` function which takes `O(n)` time and thus the recursive solution becomes O(n<sup>2</sup>) which will result in TLE(Time Limit Exceeded) for any `n` >= 10<sup>4</sup>.

Most optimized solution will be if you implement the iterative solution. It will have a time complexity of `O(n)`.

If you are still inclined to implement a recursive solution, then you can use indices such as `i` and `j` to keep track of the characters you are comparing. It will also have a time complexity of `O(n)` but it will be slower than the iterative solution due to recursion stack overhead.

---

**Recursive solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string pal(string s, int i, int j){
    if(s[i] != s[j]){
        return "BUKAN";
    }else if(i>=j){
        return "YA";
    }else{
        // since we have compared the ith and jth character
        // we need to move forward from left i.e., compare (i+1)th character, and
        // move backward from right i.e., compare (j+1)th character
        return pal(s, i+1, j-1);
    }
}

int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << pal(a, 0, a.size()-1);
}
```

---

I tried to use `i` and `j` while keeping most of the logicof the code same. But here's a shorter recursive code.
**Shorter Recursive solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string pal(string s, int i, int j){
    if(i >= j)return "YA";
    if(s[i] != s[j])return "BUKAN";
    return pal(s, i+1, j-1);
}

int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << pal(a, 0, a.size()-1);
}
```

---

---

**Update:**
As correctly pointed out by @Quimby, the recursive solution will still  be O(n^2) because whenever you will call the function, it will copy the string in the function stack space.

There are two ways to rectify this:

1. Use `&` in the function call just before the argument. This is used only in the function call argument and no where else like this.

```
string pal(string &s, int i, int j){
```

Only the line above needs to be changed and nothing else, not while calling the function through recursion or from main. Read more about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/)

2. Using `string_view`. Using this, we would have to change two lines.

```
string_view a;
string pal(string_view s, int i, int j){
```

Comment: Still `O(n^2)` due to repeated copies of `s`, use `string_view` instead of `string`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for mentioning. I did not know about this type before now.

Comment: Very useful, like `const char*` with known length and better API.